# Maintain format when displaying .txt file

Tags: c#

I am new to c# and I have a question that probably has a very simple solution. I want to import a .txt file for viewing into a textbox and maintain the format of the original file (all the correct spacings). Is this possible? I am using the following code to open the .txt files when the user clicks a button and have the files displayed. Again, I am very new to programming and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

ofd.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";

if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(ofd.FileName);
    string s = sr.ReadLine();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (s != null)
    {
        sb.Append(s);
        s = sr.ReadLine();
    }
    sr.Close();
    textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Why would the spaces disappear? And isn't it easier to use `ReadToEnd` rather than line by line reading and a string builder. That turns your code into a two liner. And I think you need a `using` in there too.

Comment: What is the problem with your current code?

Comment: What is the size of your textbox? and what is the max line length in your text file?

Comment: If your text within this file contains more than one line, then you should obviously make your textbox multiline (`txtTextBox1.Multiline = True;`). Otherwise the text will not be seen as it does in Notepad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you should use

```
sb.AppendLine();
```

instead of `sb.Append();`

now, you could (should) also use `ReadToEnd()` , as suggested by David Heffernan.

```
using(StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(ofd.FileName)) {
   textBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I replaced sb.Append(); with sb.AppendLine(); as suggested and I got the result I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are over-thinking this. There's no need for your loop and the framework already provides convenience methods that do exactly what you want.

I'd write the code like this:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ofd.FileName))
{
    textBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

I guess your question about preserving the spacing was motivated by the fact that your loop doesn't preserve line breaks. That's yet another reason for using the built-in framework. Let it take the strain and get the details right.

Comment: Thank you for the help guys. sb.AppendLine(); and 

     using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ofd.FileName))
     {
       textBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
     }

gave me the result I was looking for.

Comment: Good. It should be obvious which solution to choose to use in your program!